# How can you use tools in android layout to replace a merge item for designer

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My project contains a number of custom layouts that (mostly) extend ConstraintLayout

I use xmls like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
......
```

to create the views and then I inflate them in my code

The problem is that I can't really see the changes I make to the view unless I change the merge tag with ConstraintLayout

Is there a tools parameter that could help me in this, so that they would at least show correctly in the designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `tools:parentTag` attribute to your `merge` tag with appropriate value should allow you to see the layout in the Preview window. Depending on which library you use it should be either

```
tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout"
```

or

```
tools:parentTag="android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"
```

To be able to use the `tools` namespace you also need to add

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to your `merge` tag.